# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Update to static final field org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.ajc$tjp_0 attempted from a different method (ajc$preClinit)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcptt

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Update to static final field org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.ajc$tjp_0 attempted from a different method (ajc$preClinit) than the initializer method

I am able to launch my product and its working fine, While running rcptt with my product then this issue is coming.
I am upgrading to java 11 and eclipse 4.23.

Comment: After replacing this jar from my workspace with latest version this got resolved. 
from org.aspectj.weaver_1.8.6.20150608154244.jar
to aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar